# MySQL count data from combination of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I would appreciate your help with this task.

I have to use data from two tables:

`tourist_country` (`tourist_id`, `country_id`), and

`tourist_age_category` (`tourist_id`, `age_category_id`).

I know how to get number of tourists for each country id, and number of tourists for each age category. But what I need is the number of tourists for each country_id but with a specific age category.

I believe I'm close to my answer when joining those tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM tourist_age_category
  JOIN tourist_country ON tourist_country.tourist_id = tourist_age_category.tourist_id
```

But it hasn't gotten me anywhere so I ask for help, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: I tried all kinds of joins. I believe I'm close to my answer when joining those tables 
SELECT * FROM 
 tourist_age_category
 join tourist_country ON tourist_country.tourist_id = tourist_age_categroy.tourist_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand what you mean, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT country_id, age_category_id, count(*)
FROM tourist_age_category
  JOIN tourist_country ON tourist_country.tourist_id = tourist_age_category.tourist_id
GROUP BY country_id, age_category_id
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!